# Gesture recognizer doesn't work on UICollectionView inside of other UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I created a UICollectionView as a major UICollectionView and each collectionViewCell has another UICollectionView "B" as it's subview 
Then I add a tapGesture in "B". but "B" can't trigger this gesture.
Following is my main code:

Main UICollectionView

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class mainViewController :UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.mainCollectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "OuterCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "OuterCollectionViewCell")
        self.mainCollectionView.delegate = self
        self.mainCollectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("OuterCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OuterCollectionViewCell
        return cell
    }

}
```

UICollectionView B:

```
class OuterCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var InnerCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        InnerCollectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "InnerCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CellInner")
    }

    func handleTapGesture(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tapguesture")
    }

    override func didMoveToWindow(){
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTapGesture:")
        InnerCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        InnerCollectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        InnerCollectionView.delegate = self
        InnerCollectionView.dataSource = self

    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CellInner", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! InnerCollectionViewCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

This issue is bugging me an whole day. Is there anyone who has any ideas about how to fix this issue?

I have uploaded the project into github: https://github.com/dengchicheng/Test2

**update－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－**

today I init the innerCollectionView by code programmably instead of init by NIB. and it works

```
let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
let InnerCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 600), collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
```

I don't know what the NIB did to the UIcollectionview
I did set the userInteractive to be true in the interface builder

Comment: is your `InnerCollectionView.userInteractionEnable` set to `true` ?

Comment: yes set true no affect